# Does there exist a Noetherian domain (which is not a field) whose field of fractions is (isomorphic with) $\mathbb C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, noetherian, integral-domain

> Does there exist a Noetherian domain which is not a field whose field of fractions is (isomorphic with) $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: Perhaps related to [this unanswered question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1872470/110831), where the same is asked for $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5):

If there is such a Noetherian domain $R$ of positive dimension, we may assume it to be one-dimensional by passing to a localization at a height one prime. Passing further to the integral closure of $R$ within ${\mathbb C}$ (which is again Noetherian by the Krull-Akizuki Theorem), we may even assume $R$ to be normal, hence a discrete valuation ring corresponding to a discrete valuation $\eta: {\mathbb C}^{\times}\to {\mathbb Z}$.

However, there is no discrete valuation on ${\mathbb C}$, because as explained in [every field of characteristic 0 has a discrete valuation ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374553/every-field-of-characteristic-0-has-a-discrete-valuation-ring) the value group of each valuation of ${\mathbb C}^{\times}$ needs to be divisible due to the presence of arbitrarily high roots in ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: @Saun Dev: Do you have any questions?

Comment: if such a Noetherian domain , which is not a field , exists then it must have positive dimension , then passing to a height one prime ideal we have a Noetherian domain of dimension 1 and then taking its integral closure , since the field of fractions remains the same , and the integral closure is still Noetherian (by say Krull-Akizuki theorem) we may assume our Noetherian domain is normal also . Now let aa be a positive real number which irreducible in our normal Noetherian domain , then $(a) \subset (\sqrt a) \subset (\sqrt{\sqrt a })\subset ...$ gives a non-ending ascending chain

Comment: could you please check if my above argument works ? I think the only problem it might face is that some square root of square root of ... $a$ might turn out to be a unit ... can we somehow make the argument work ?